# Why does an error occur when you try to assign values to an array with arr = {values};?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, variable-assignment

Why isn't it in C (or C++) allowed?

I mean this:

```
ucell GetPlayerPosPositionData[5];
GetPlayerPosPositionData = {4*sizeof(cell),playerid,0,sizeof(cell),2*sizeof(cell)};//this does not work, error

//normal assignment
GetPlayerPosPositionData[1] = playerid;
GetPlayerPosPositionData[2] = 0;
GetPlayerPosPositionData[3] = sizeof(cell);
GetPlayerPosPositionData[4] = 2*sizeof(cell);
```

Comment: typedef unsigned int ucell;

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201101/how-to-initialize-an-array-in-c)

Comment: Try `ucell GetPlayerPosPositionData[5] = {4*sizeof(cell),playerid,0,sizeof(cell),2*sizeof(cell)};`

Comment: @otibom, assignment and initialization are two different things.

Comment: @Zane that is initialization, not assignment.

Comment: You can only initialize arrays with an initializer list, not assign them. You can use `std::vector` to that effect, though: `std::vector<int> v; v = {1, 2, 3};`

Comment: @chris you always have such great tips :D

Comment: @GamErix, Well, this one only works in C++11 :)

Comment: I does automaticly push/resize the vector?

Comment: @GamErix After the assignment, the vector only contains the elements you assigned. Everything else is cleared.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the syntax says it is not allowed?  There are two parts to the problem:

1. You can't use the initializer syntax except in an initializer or (in C99) in a compound literal.
2. You can't assign whole arrays.

In C99, you could pass an array to a function:

```
typedef unsigned int cell;

extern void some_func(cell data[]);

extern void func(void);

void func(void)
{
    cell playerid = 0;
    some_func((cell[]){4*sizeof(cell),playerid,0,sizeof(cell),2*sizeof(cell)});
}
```

(Your question is unclear on `cell` vs `ucell`; I chose to use `cell` throughout.)

You still can't do array assignment.  If the array is wrapped in  a structure, you can do the structure assignment which, coincidentally, assigns the contained array.  But that is a structure assignment, not an array assignment.

Comment: You're not actually passing an array to `some_func`.  The function receives a pointer to the first element of `data`, regardless of the argument notation.

Comment: The literal array decays to a pointer to the first element when it is passed to the function — yes, of course, just like any other array would decay into a pointer to the first element.  But the compound literal notation has created a literal array.

Comment: Yes, of course.  I suppose I'm a bit hypersensitive to arrays and their semantics because so few people really understand the difference (I realize that you do, the comment was for the OP and others).

Comment: Arrays and pointers are a source of confusion.  Another way of looking at it would be with `extern void another_func(cell (*data)[5]);`, a function which takes a pointer to an array of 5 `cell` values.  I could invoke: `another_func(&(cell[]){4*sizeof(cell),playerid,0,sizeof(cell),2*sizeof(cell)});` which would not work if the compound literal was not an actual array.

Comment: Yep.  Pointers to arrays are even less well understood.

Answer (score 2):

Because arrays are not assignable.  You can initialize them at the point of declaration or you can assign them on a per-element basis, but that's it.  This would work:

```
ucell GetPlayerPosPositionData[] = {4*sizeof(cell),
                                    playerid,
                                    0,
                                    sizeof(cell),
                                    2*sizeof(cell)};
```

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is for list-initializing an array. It can only be used as the initializer of your array declaration:

```
ucell GetPlayerPosPositionData[5] = {4*sizeof(cell),playerid,0,sizeof(cell),2*sizeof(cell)};
```

The alternative is to individually assign to each of the elements:

```
ucell GetPlayerPosPositionData[5];
GetPlayerPosPositionData[0] = 4 * sizeof(cell);
GetPlayerPosPositionData[1] = playerid;
GetPlayerPosPositionData[2] = 0;
GetPlayerPosPositionData[3] = sizeof(cell);
GetPlayerPosPositionData[4] = 2 * sizeof(cell);
```

Answer (score 0):

I will let the language lawyers argue over this. Suppose `array` is declared as `int array[4]`, and you wish to assign to it. Then consider:

```
* (struct t { int array[4]; } *) array = (struct t) {{ 0, 1, 2, 3 }};
```